# How do I find out if my server is a spambot?

Tags: email, malware

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have an email server and web site hosted.

Lately i have been getting tens of thousands of "return to sender
 and "delayed" email error messages for Viagra spam and such supposedly originating from my server.

Checked for the likely Linux malware, nothing found. Installed maldetect - it found nothing also.

What can I do to find out whether I have a spambot living in my system?

Here's my main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu) biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job. append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key smtpd_use_tls=yes smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.xxxxxxx.org
# alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
# alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases myorigin = xxxxxxx.org mydestination =  relayhost =  mynetworks = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.0/24
# [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
# mynetworks_style = host mailbox_size_limit = 0 recipient_delimiter = + inet_interfaces = all masquerade_domains = mail.xxxxxxx.org local_recipient_maps =

# how long if undelivered before sending warning update to sender  delay_warning_time = 4h 

# how long to keep message on queue before return as failed. 
# some have 3 days, I have 16 days as I am backup server for some people 
# whom go on holiday with their server switched off.  maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d 

# max and min time in seconds between retries if connection failed  minimal_backoff_time = 1000s  maximal_backoff_time = 8000s 

# how long to wait when servers connect before receiving rest of data  smtp_helo_timeout = 60s 

# how many address can be used in one message. 
# effective stopper to mass spammers, accidental copy in whole address list 
# but may restrict intentional mail shots.  smtpd_recipient_limit = 16 

# how many error before back off.  smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3 

# how many max errors before blocking it.  smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

# Requirements for the HELO statement  smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit

# Requirements for the sender details  smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit 

# Requirements for the connecting server smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org 

# Requirement for the recipient address 

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,    reject_unauth_pipelining,   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,  check_policy_service unix:private/policy, 
        reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com,
        reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,
        reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
        reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
        reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net,
        reject_rbl_client rabl.nuclearelephant.com,     check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
        permit

# require proper helo at connections  smtpd_helo_required = yes 

# waste spammers time before rejecting them  smtpd_delay_reject = yes  disable_vrfy_command = yes strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes invalid_hostname_reject_code = 554 multi_recipient_bounce_reject_code
= 554 non_fqdn_reject_code = 554 relay_domains_reject_code = 554 unknown_address_reject_code = 554 unknown_client_reject_code = 554 unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554 unknown_local_recipient_reject_code
= 554 unknown_relay_recipient_reject_code = 554 unknown_sender_reject_code = 554 unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 554 unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 554 unverified_recipient_reject_code = 554 unverified_sender_reject_code = 554

# not sure of the difference of the next two 
# but they are needed for local aliasing  alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases  alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases 

# this specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located  virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual 

# this is for the mailbox location for each user  virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf 

# and this is for aliases  virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf 

# and this is for domain lookups  virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf 

# this is how to connect to the domains (all virtual, but the option is there) 
# not used yet 
# transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transport.cf

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000  virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# SASL smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# If your potential clients use Outlook Express or other older clients
# this needs to be set to yes broken_sasl_auth_clients = no smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that your system is compromised; most probably you just have an [open mail relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay), which spammers can exploit to send spam. Basically, they're exploiting your SMTP server to send their spam email.

Ensure that your mailserver accepts mail from localhost only, or otherwise enable SMTP authentication for remote clients.  (How to do that depends on the mailserver software you're running.)

Comment: Should have mentioned - I've made all the mods I could find to the Postfix config files to prevent an open relay.

Comment: I need to move this to my Linux box to add config file text.

Comment: Do you need your server to accept mail from other remote servers, or only from localhost?

Comment: I only access from my local network - want all send access from outside disabled.

Comment: Then add a firewall rule to allow incoming connections to port 25 only from those IPs on your LAN that need to send mail, and deny all other connections to port 25.